# Is it safe to add more than primary data file to Temp DB in SQL server 2008 R2 as we have database server with 4 Core processor?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is it safe to add more than primary data file to Temp DB in SQL server 2008 R2 as we have database server with 4  Core processor and please tell me the steps to do it .And does it will tune performance?

Tip : Our Temp DB size is about 22 GB which is bigger than our Production database and does it normal?

Comment: A little help: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/cheat-sheet-how-to-configure-tempdb-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

The article linked by @McNets is a good one. 
**The One And Only One** article has code you can use: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/tempdb-data-files/

Because you only have 4 cores, you can probably just create a total of 4 TempDB files.

If you use the code snippet in Brent's article, make sure you match up the beginning of the file name section:

```
FILENAME = N'
```

with the folder directories you already have.

You don't have to restart the engine if you're not shrinking the the original file while adding these. As for the size, it's not necesaarily a bad thing that it is bigger than your prod database, though it could be indiciative of something. Do you delete a bunch of records out fo there recently?

Comment: Really,, I didn't delete any records

Comment: Perhaps you did some heavy processing in tempDB, but honestly unless you're running out of space, 22 GB TempDB is not something I would worry too much about. Is there a lot of space available? Perhaps someone created a lot of global temp tables and didn't drop them, look in the list of temporary tables for ##___ and don't just drop them if they're there, but look into why.

Comment: Please could you guide  me how is to discover this temp tables ? as may Our ERP use it and I already have enough spaces on our server drives ? and how can I discover the session which make my Temp DB to be  bigger to monitor  it's behavior and my I kill it ? Thanks on advance